# Gauss Curvature (Differential Geometry)

Tags: parametric, curvature, gaussian-elimination

Let $X(u, v)$ be a parameterization of a surface $M$ so that the first fundamental form is $I = h^2(du^2 + dv^2)$. Show that the Gauss curvature

$K = -\frac{1}{h^2}(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial v^2})\log h$

I don't know where to really start. I took the derivative of $I$ and I've been looking at the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem and other theorems in my notes but I've been stuck on this for a while now. Personally, this is a very difficult section for me in the class and no tutoring is offered for this class at my school. Can someone please help?

Comment: Forget the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. It's not appropriate here. Do you know a formula for the Gaussian curvature when you're in an orthogonal coordinate system (no $du\,dv$ term in the metric)? If your text and course are not helpful in this regard, you might want to look at my (free) differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: would the first and second fundamental form of the surface apply to this question at all? It's impressive that you have your own text! I can't imagine being so skilled in such a topic. Also someone just submitted an answer below, would you mind double checking his work? This class is really important to me and my goal is to pass with at least a B, so far I'm on track. But I could definitely use your knowledge.

Comment: You know nothing about the second fundamental form here. Jimbo is using the correct formula for $K$ (the one I asked you if you knew). I got my Ph.D. in geometry and was a professor for 35+ years, so, yes, I know this stuff well. :) But you should worry more about understanding material than about getting a grade.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\dim{M}=2$ and the metric $ds^2= E(u, v)du^2+G(u, v)dv^2$. Then the Gauss curvature $K$ is given by

$$K=−\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}
\left(\left(\dfrac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_u+\left(\dfrac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_v \right)$$

Then $E(u, v)=h^2(u, v)=G(u, v)$, imply

$$K=−\dfrac{1}{h^2}
\left(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial v^2} \right)\log{h}$$